# How to fetch data from the Jikanapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I want to call an API here
https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime to get the data in raw format and then create an array of only useful data out of it. What is the reason the data is not being consoled

```
const initialAnime = {
  anime: [],
  genresLoaded: false,
  genres: [],
};

function createAnimeFromRawData(rawData, animeArray) {
  const data = rawData.data;
  data.forEach((animeData) => {
    const anime = {
      mal_id: animeData.mal_id,
      title: animeData.title,
      title_english: animeData.title_english,
      type: animeData.type,
      episodes: animeData.episodes,
      status: animeData.status,
      duration: animeData.duration,
      rating: animeData.rating,
      rank: animeData.rank,
      synopsis: animeData.synopsis,
    };
    console.log(animeArray);
    animeArray.push(anime);
  });
}

const RawdataAnime = async (api, genre, paging) => {
  const Animearray = [];
  for (let i = 1; Animearray.length < 60 && i < 10; i++) {
    const {
      data: { results },
    } = await axios.get(`${api}`);
    createAnimeFromRawData(results, Animearray);
  }
  return Animearray;
};
export const fetchAnime = createAsyncThunk(
  "myanimelist/topAnime",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    const {
      myanimelist: { genres },
    } = thunkAPI.getState();
    return RawdataAnime(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime`, genres, false);
  }
);
const animeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Myanimelist",
  initialState: initialAnime,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getGenresAnime.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.genres = action.payload;
      state.genresLoaded = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAnime.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.anime = action.payload;
    });
  },
});
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    netflix: netflixSlice.reducer,
    anime: animeSlice.reducer,
  },
});
```

I tried the code above to get an array of only useful parts of data in the code but there was nothing in the console. There was no error and no output.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the response.data will be something similar to the json below::

```
{
  "pagination":{
    ...
  },
  "data":[
    ...
  ],
  "links":{
    ...
  },
  "meta":{
    ...
  }
}
```

I believe the error is in the snippet

```js
const { data: { results }} = await axios.get(`${api}`); // There are no results in the returned content
createAnimeFromRawData(results, Animearray);
```

Try something like

```js
const { data } = await axios.get(`${api}`); // Equivalent to response.data
const results = data?.data || []
createAnimeFromRawData(results, Animearray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still nothing is getting consoled.

Comment: If you have a github (or similar) repository for the project, share or try to reproduce your code using a codesandbox (or similar). This would make it easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the effort , i have just solved it and it was due to some  this line
const results = data?.data || []

Comment: i re wrote it as  const results = data?.data || []
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime`); // Equivalent to response.data
    const results = data?.data || [];

    try {
      await createAnimeFromRawData(results, Animearray);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } 
and it worked

Comment: Good. I'm glad to have helped,